# No such file or directory during cap deploy:update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I noticed in the output from cap deploy:update, that it is triggering "deploy:assets:precompile" as an after callback for deploy:update_code:

```
triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-05-15 11:32:16 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * 2013-05-15 11:32:16 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
  * executing "[ -e /home/johnmerlino/public_html/store.johnmerlino.com/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /home/johnmerlino/public_html/store.johnmerlino.com/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
    servers: ["xxx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 314ms
  * executing "cd -- /home/johnmerlino/public_html/store.johnmerlino.com/releases/20130515153214 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["xxx.xx.xx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] executing command
 ** [out :: xxx.xx.xx.xxx] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: xxx.xx.xx.xxx] No such file or directory - /home/johnmerlino/public_html/store.johnmerlino.com/releases/20130515153214/config/config.yml
 ** [out :: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

Now the problem there is it says that the latest release doesn't have a "config.yml" file.

Actually in my capistrano script, that file is created after "deploy:update_code":

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:symlink_shared_configs"

namespace :deploy do

 desc "Symlink configuration files"
 task :symlink_shared_configs, :roles => [:db,:app] do
   run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
   run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/config.yml #{release_path}/config/config.yml"
 end

 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

So shouldn't config.yml be created by this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are being triggered in the list of callbacks for `after deploy:update_code` then they're essentially part of the same callback group, but the order in which callbacks in the same group are called depends [on the implementation of the callback registration and execution](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/h/HeSYINUvSBZfxqA-capistrano-2.5.27/Capistrano/Configuration/Callbacks.html).

If you need them to run in a given order then you can explicitly change when `assets:precompile` is run by moving it later, or moving the `config.yml` file earlier in order to guarantee that one comes before the other.

As it stands now, since they both run in the `after deploy:update_code` the order in which they get executed could be either:

```
  ...before...
deploy:update_code
  ...after...                     | after group
  deploy:symlink_shared_configs   | after group
  deploy:assets:precompile        | after group
```

...OR...

```
  ...before...
deploy:update_code
  ...after...                     | after group
  deploy:assets:precompile        | after group
  deploy:symlink_shared_configs   | after group
```

...and based on the fact that you've posted this question, it sounds like the latter instance is happening for you.

Comment: Well, I read somewhere that load 'deploy/assets' should be placed in Capfile. BUt according to your instructions, in order for this to work, I had to place load 'deploy/assets' after the line after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:symlink_shared_configs" in my deploy.rb file. It worked but I thought that load deploy/assets belonged in Capfile

Comment: that might work but I wasn't suggesting moving the `load` statement - I meant to change the callback that triggers `deploy:assets:precompile` so that it's triggered after the symlink. I didn't mean to physically move the line of code - but to change the execution order by changing the callback it's tied to. The fact that it's working by moving the `load` statement is fragile, and will break as soon as someone edits that file again and inadvertently changes the order back the other way, whereas changing the callback that triggers it is a more robust and permanent way to enforce execution order.